# Is there any way to turn down the fan speed on a Dell T7500?

Tags: windows-7, noise

I have a Dell T7500, with a 6-core Xeon CPU.

- If I run all CPUs at 100% for 12 hours, the fan noise is loud.
- If I run all CPUs at 1% (no load) for 12 hours, the fan noise is just as loud (i.e. fan speed is the same).

Its just too noisy (I run it in my living room) - any utility to turn down the fan speed on a Dell?

Comment: Found http://www.diefer.de/i8kfan/. It fails on Win7 with "Windows requires a digitally signed driver". I wonder how I can switch off this limitation for digitally signed drivers in Win 7?

Comment: How about the BIOS settings? Is it a 4-pin power connector (should be)?  http://www.allpinouts.org/index.php/Motherboard_%28CPU%29_4_Pin_Fan

Comment: "Over 1 billion possible configurations configurable to virtually any industry, application or environment. " promised by Dell, but the CPU fan stuck on fullspeed, strange...

Comment: Have you updated your BIOS? This could also be a setting in your BIOS to control the fan speed. I would not look into any third party app because it will only help you once Windows is loaded. I would see if you're missing something within the BIOS.

Comment: "By using this software you are changing the thermal management of your DELL notebook. " But isn't it a desktop PC? http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/precision-t7500/pd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, the answer appears to be: no.

Go Dell, you're awesome.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Do you have something to back-up your claims? Why doesn't it work for you?